# firebase list shows no apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Just reinstalled my mac and when I cloned my code that has been deployed to firebase hosting in the past, is now not deploying. I installed firebase tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then I run the following command in the project main directory

```
firebase login
firebase list
```

My app is not being displayed. I know things have switched over to google but not sure what to do to solve this. Thanks

Firebase-tools version

```
2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase tools is upgraded to **3.0.0** right now if you've migrated over.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools

v2 of Firebase is not completely forwards compatible to the migrated instances. I'd highly recommend that you update.

Comment: I misread the error message when I had 3.0 installed. Upgraded and now it works

Comment:  Make sure not to use v2 libraries with v3.0. Though the DB libraries seem to work fine I wouldn't count on the auxiliary tools to work at the moment.